# How do I pass the userId into the model ASP.NET MVC?

Tags: asp.net-mvc, entity-framework

I've had a thorough search around but really can't find anything addressing the scenario I'm facing (oddly because I'd have thought it's quite a common thing to do).

### Background

I'm creating an application with ASP.NET MVC 4 and Entity Framework 5 Code First.  For the purpose of this question, think of it as a blogging application with posts and users.

### Project

The post model requires that every post have a corresponding UserId.

With the ASP.NET MVC 4 Membership it is easy to find the username of the person logged in with

`User.Identity.Name`.

This isn't ideal, we want the ID, but a query such as this can search the db for the name and get the ID.

`db.UserProfiles.Single(a => a.UserName == User.Identity.Name);`

### Problem

The problem arises when trying to create a post. `Model.IsValid` is false, as no UserId is being passed in from the view.  Obviously, as the user isn't expected to enter their ID.

I've tried putting the ID value into the `ViewBag` and using a `@Html.Hidden()` field in the view, however I've had no success with this. `Model.IsValid` always returns false.

Should this information be input through the create view?  Or should it be done directly in the controller?  Its quite a frustrating problem as I have the information and just need to figure how to pass it into the model.

#### CONTROLLER CODE

This is basically just the default scaffolded code.  The commented code is how I tried setting the model value directly from the controller, however that was little more than trial and error.

```
    //
    // POST: /Post/Create

    [HttpPost]
    [ValidateAntiForgeryToken]
    public ActionResult Create(Post post)
    {
        if (ModelState.IsValid)
        {
            //var userId = db.UserProfiles.Single(a => a.UserName == User.Identity.Name);
            //post.User.UserId = userId.UserId;
            db.Posts.Add(post);
            db.SaveChanges();
            return RedirectToAction("Index");
        }
        return View(post);
    }
```

Comment: pls show you code: controller action, view and model

Comment: show generated html markup for your hidden userId property.

Answer (score 3):

Be careful with hidden fields. Anyone could put whatever value they want in that field (i.e. they could spoof another user). You'd be better off caching the ID in the session at login, and using that value.

Comment: Hidden fields are very subject to injection. Anyone can manipulate them and they should not be considered as "secure".

Answer (score 2):

This is a typical case where you want to create an `EditModel` as a data transfer object (DTO) between your view and controller layers.

Create a class `BlogPostEditModel` that has all properties you need the user to fill in when creating a new blog post. Then, map this type (e.g. using AutoMapper) to your `BlogPost` entity, and fill in the user ID as well.

To use built-in validation such as `Model.IsValid()`, put the data annotations attributes on the DTO instead.

Comment: An alternative solution is to create an action filter which sets the value for you.

Comment: Your comment should be your answer in my opinion. I do not understand why people insist on using their db mapped entities as view models, but if they do at the very least they could pair that with a filter on their actions.

Comment: Thanks for your input Tomas.  I'll look into creating a intermediary model.

Comment: @TravisJ: The main reason to keep the comment as a comment and not in the answer is because I think creating a DTO is a much better solution than an action filter.

Answer (score 2):

Honestly, I would have the value assigned via the controller. If you had someone messing with your html via Firebug, they could actually change the id before it was passed and submitted to your form. I would remove it from your Create view and submit from the controller.

Comment: I would prefer to have this done in the controller as well. Html is not secure enough to trust for something as paramount as a user id.

Comment: This is definitely the most ideal option I was trying to achieve before asking the question. I did attempt doing this, by accessing the object the setting the userId field to the right value as per `post.User.UserId = userId.UserId;` Is this the correct way of setting a model value in the controller?